# Boto3 wait_until_exists for available image (object has not attribute)

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3, boto, amazon-ami

I'm creating an AMI and I want to wait until the AMI is 'available'. I'm using the following code:

```
import json
import boto3
import os
import logging

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

images = ec2.create_image(
    Name='test2021-2',
    InstanceId='i-f966b43b',
    #DryRun=True,
    Description='This is a test with the latest AMI'    
)

images.wait_until_exists(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'State',
            'Values': [
                'available',
            ]
        },
    ],
)
```

But I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'wait_until_exists'

The waiter is not waiting until the AMI is available.

Comment: According to the docs, ```create_image``` returns a ```dict```  And from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969465/usage-of-wait-until-exists-or-wait-until-running-method-in-boto3-image-in-am  I think you need to use ```image = Image(<instanceid>)``` and then ```image.wait_until_exists()```  Check the link for more help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one step. First you have to create the waiter using [get_waiter](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.ImageExists):

```
images = ec2.create_image(
    Name='test2021-2',
    InstanceId='i-f966b43b',
    #DryRun=True,
    Description='This is a test with the latest AMI'    
)

waiter = ec2.get_waiter('image_exists')

# you may need to fill out the proper arguments for `wait`

waiter.wait(
    ImageIds=[
        'string',
    ], 
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'state',
            'Values': [
                'available',
            ]
        },
    ],
)
```